# Wait for browser to render element in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using CSS `transition` with `top` and `left` to animate the movement of an element in React.

To achieve this, the component must first be rendered with `top: 0; left: 0`, and then re-rendered with altered `top` and `left` properties to start the transition.

This is my component:

```js
export default class Animator extends React.Component{

    render(){
        var top = 0;
        var left = 0;

        if(this.state.moving){
            top = this.props.top;
            left = this.props.left;
        }

        return(
            <div 
            className="red-box animator" 
            style={{
                top: `{top}px`,
                left: `{left}px`}}>
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({moving: true});
    }
}
```

```css
.animator{
    position: absolute;
    transition: top 0.5s, left 0.5s;
}

.red-box{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I expected the component to be rendered by the browser before `componentDidMount` fires, but I found that this isn't the case.

As a result, the `top` and `left` properties are updated too soon and the component appears immediately in its destination position with no transition.

Changing my componentDidMount function to have a delay solves the problem, but too short of a delay makes the functionality unreliable (especially on slower devices), and I don't want a longer delay as I want the element to be moving as soon as it appears on the screen.

```js
componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({moving: true});
    }, 150);
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that I only update the state once the browser has rendered the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers optimize render and are not rerendering stuff that changed in the same animation frame. They merge changes and render the end result. To mitigate that you may use `requestAnimationFrame` trick:

```js
componenetDidMount() {
  self.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.setState({ moving: true })
}
```

Keep in mind that though `requestAnimationFrame` is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/requestanimationframe) among browsers some really old ones might need a polifill or prefix to make it work.

Comment: Using your example didn't fix the problem in React, but I found that if I added an extra requestAnimationFrame call then the problem was resolved reliably. My final code in componentDidMount is: `requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => this.setState({ moving: true })));`. Thank you very much for your help!